# EEVEE renders blank frames

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, blend-files

I'm trying to render an animation frame by frame in EEVEE for a personal project, this is the third shot so it has the exact same render settings as the previous 2 shots but when I hit render animation, blender either struggles to render the first frame or renders a black, empty frame. every frame. The scene has is the smallest of the three shots I've rendered so I doubt it'll be due to an image texture/ model overload, but I could be wrong!

I've searched online and tried what I could find but nothing seems to be working. TIA for any help

[Here is the blender file for reference.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fry3yEoUBRSE7HlVn5AmbQ0rgdjHSSQX/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5):

Just disable your hidden side wall from rendering.

[image]

Comment: i know it would be obvious. didn't expect it to be that obvious. Thanks so much! aha